# How to swap column values using a condition where values contain part of a string using python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a large dataset about 300 rows. I have data that is in the incorrect columns. I have tried `np.where` but can't seem to get it right.

```
   A      B      C
1  AD75   5222   CD56
2  CD45   5233   AD58
3  5267   CD45   AD55
4  5200   AD45   CD46
```

desired output

```
    A      B      C
1  AD75   5222   CD56
2  AD58   5233   CD45
3  AD55   5267   CD45
4  AD45   5200   CD46
```

Col A needs to have values that start with AD, col B needs to have an int value and col C must have values that start with CD

Comment: What is the rule converting input to output?

Comment: Col A needs to have values that start with AD, col B needs to have an int value and col C must have values that start with CD

Answer (score 1):

I believe this requires a case-by-case analysis, this would be my approach:

```
list_A = [[x for x in y if str(x).startswith('A')][0] for y in df.values]
list_B = [[x for x in y if type(x) == int][0] for y in df.values]
list_C = [[x for x in y if str(x).startswith('C')][0] for y in df.values]
df['A'] = list_A
df['B'] = list_B
df['C'] = list_C
```

Output:

```
      A     B     C
0  AD75  5222  CD56
1  AD58  5233  CD45
2  AD55  5267  CD45
3  AD45  5200  CD46
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
# you can sort the rows
df2 = df.apply(sorted, 1).to_frame()[0].apply(pd.Series)

# set column names
df2.columns = ['B','A', 'C']
cols = sorted(df2.columns)

df2 = df2[cols]
print(df2)

      A     B     C
1  AD75  5222  CD56
2  AD58  5233  CD45
3  AD55  5267  CD45
4  AD45  5200  CD46
```

Comment: This sounds like an incredibly roundabout approach

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what the condition is under which you want to swap the values in the columns. I am assuming that whenever colum `B` looks like an integer, you want to swap:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_clipboard()
print(df)
# swap integers into column B
ind = ~df['B'].str.match("\d+")
df.loc[ind, ['A', 'B']] = df.loc[ind, ['B', 'A']].values
# swap strings starting with "AB" into column A
ind = ~df['A'].str.match("^AD")
df.loc[ind, ['A', 'C']] = df.loc[ind, ['C', 'A']].values

print(df)
```

This yields:

```
      A     B     C
1  AD75  5222  CD56
2  CD45  5233  AD58
3  5267  CD45  AD55
4  5200  AD45  CD46

      A     B     C
1  AD75  5222  CD56
2  AD58  5233  CD45
3  AD55  5267  CD45
4  AD45  5200  CD46
```

Comment: Col A needs to have values that start with AD, col B needs to have an int value and col C must have values that start with CD